# PHP - get project directory path on MacOsX apache

Tags: php, apache, phpstorm

I'm getting different results while retrieving the root directory path of my project folder under different environments: **phpstorm8 browser debugger** and **Mac OSX apache2**

PHP version: `5.6.6`

Apache: `Server version: Apache/2.2.26 (Unix)`

My Mac OSX Apache directory is

> /Library/WebServer/Documents/projectfolder

I'm using phpStorm8 and my workspace directory is

> /Users/myname/Documents/workspace/php/projectfolder

My folder structure is like this:

```
-projectfolder/
  -config/
     config.php
  - subfolder
     index.php
  index.php
```

Below is a snippet on how I am getting the root directory of my project

```
echo "document_root:" . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
```

Under phpStorm8 debugging environment, I'm getting:

```
document_root:/Users/myname/Documents/workspace/php/projectfolder
```

In Mac OSX apache, I'm getting:

```
document_root:/Library/WebServer/Documents
```

Why is it in Mac OSX apache, I'm not able to get the root directory of my project folder?

**In Mac OSX apache:**
[image: screenshot from Mac OSX apache]

**In phpStorm8 in built apache**
[image: phpStorm8 in built apache]

As you can see in the second pic, I am able to get the project root folder 'moviex'. I remember last time I was able to get this same result in WAMP, MAMP, or even CentOS. Is there any special setting in Mac OSX apache that's preventing me from doing so?

Comment: Screenshots please of 1) how you debugging it and 2) how URLs are looking in both cases. It's possible that you are using built-in web server in one case (or even CLI debug) and proper Apache in another.

Comment: Hi I have added screenshots for clarity. phpStorm8 has fastcgi enabled

Comment: As suspected: first one is handled by Apache from `/Library/WebServer/Documents` folder while second one is served by PhpStorm's own simple built-in server where project root will be = document root. To tell PhpStorm to use your Apache you need to configure Deployment entry of correct type and mark it as Default for this project -- then all URLs used when opening page in browser will use your custom Apache instead of built-in server: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Deployments+in+PhpStorm ; http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/webinar-recording-deployment-with-phpstorm/

Comment: I think @LazyOne has right. That should be a built-in webserver.

Comment: phpstorm is able to return my project root Dir but not Mac osx apache. Correct me if I'm wrong but $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is suppose to do so right

Comment: It all depends on your Apache config. As far as I'm aware (based on my Apache experience) -- it's all correct here and you need to configure your Apache differently if you want to have `/Users/myname/Documents/workspace/php/projectfolder` to be returned by Apache as document root (but then your URL will be slightly different as well).

Comment: Ohh I get what u mean. I should set my document root to my project folder and the URL will be say just localhost

Comment: Correct. You can also use virtual hosts and fake any domain name via local `hosts` file (or local DNS server if you have one); then you can use `my-project.dev` (for example) to access one site and `another.project.dev` for another -- much better than `localhost/my-project` and close to real world site (i.e. `www.my-project.com`)